# Good introduction to SVG

Tags: html, svg

Could anyone recommend a good introduction to SVG?

I'm looking for a good tutorial that covers what SVG is, and the basics of how to use it.

I've Googled, of course, but I don't see an introduction that I immediately trust.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Richard, unfortunately, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  It's a totally fine question, just not one that can live under the scope of what StackOverflow is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [SVG Primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html) over at the W3C. It's from a member of the SVG Working Group, trustworthy as it can get.

The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG) has references to elements and attributes.

And then there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553014/a-good-beginners-tutorial-on-svg) already answered with a ton of good references. Let me emphasize @p00ya's answer to read the specification. It's well written and it's what I used to learn SVG. You can also trust @Erik Dahlström to know what he talks about, he, too, is a member of the W3C SVG Working Group.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the [1st chapter on the free sampler](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781449374358_sampler.pdf) of *"SVG Essentials, Producing Scalable Vector Graphics with XML"* (2nd Edition), by J. David Eisenberg and Amelia Bellamy-Royds (who also wrote this nice article [How to Scale SVG](http://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)).